# Unable to Deserialize HttpResponseMessage to Model Object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

1. Code for Getting the `Response`:

   ```
   public async Task<List<RepositoryListResponseItem>> MakeGitRequestAsync<T>(string url)
   {
       List<RepositoryListResponseItem> res = new List<RepositoryListResponseItem>();
       using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
       {
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpFactoryTesting");
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


           using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
           {
               if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
               {
                   string apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                   res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RepositoryListResponseItem>>(apiResponse);
               }
           }

       }
       return res;
   }
   ```
2. Model Object:

   ```
   public class RepositoryListResponseItem
   {
       [Description("Repo Name")]
       [JsonPropertyName("full_name")]
       public string RepoName { get; set; }

       [Description("Repo Link")]
       [JsonPropertyName("html_url")]
       public string RepoLink { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   3. HttpWebResponse after I get it in string (`string apiResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`)

      ```
      [{\"id\":114995175,\"node_id\":\"MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkxMTQ5OTUxNzU=\",\"name\":\"AlcoholConsumption\",\"full_name\":\"ihri/AlcoholConsumption\",\....
      ```

I have C#.NET service, where I am consuming GitHub APIs. I am able to successfully get the data, but unfortunately in the incorrect format(please check step 3). 
I am not able to convert the response to my custom object)

Here, the response is `JSONarray` to be precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your `Json` results, it seems your model object needs to be something like this:

```
public class RepositoryListResponseItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string node_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
}
```

Also I would strongly recommend you to use the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) keyword instead of `Result`:

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: That worked. I want to know if I can make this method for generic type say T?

Answer (score 1):

`JsonPropertyName` is a attribute of System.Text.Json.

`[JsonProperty("name")]` is a attribute of Newtonsoft.

**if System.Text.Json is to be used:**

```
public class RepositoryListResponseItem
{
    [Description("Repo Name")]
    [JsonPropertyName("full_name")]
    public string RepoName { get; set; }

    [Description("Repo Link")]
    [JsonPropertyName("html_url")]
    public string RepoLink { get; set; }
}
```

deseralize:

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
res = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<RepositoryListResponseItem>>(apiResponse);
```

**if Newtonsoft.Json is to be used:**

```
public class RepositoryListResponseItem
{
    [Description("Repo Name")]
    [JsonProperty("full_name")]
    public string RepoName { get; set; }

    [Description("Repo Link")]
    [JsonProperty("html_url")]
    public string RepoLink { get; set; }
}
```

deserialize:

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RepositoryListResponseItem>>(apiResponse);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for this question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use your custom class at object type

```
var jsonString = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(jsonString);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).